# Function is telling me the length of the string and not the number of occurrences of the char inputted by the user

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countLetters(char *string1, char letter){   
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(string1); i++){
        if(string1[i]=letter){
        count++;
        }
    }    
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char string1[200];
    char letter;
    int count;

    printf("\nEnter the string: \n");
    fgets(string1, 200, stdin);

    printf("\nEnter character to be searched: \n");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    
    count = countLetters(string1, letter);

    printf("\nThe number of occurrences: %d", count);
}
```

I was expecting for the function to output the number of times each letter of the array was equal to the char(letter) inputted by the user, but it is just giving me the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line:

```
    if(string1[i]=letter){
```

to

```
    if(string1[i]==letter){
```

Note, that the string1[i]=letter was overwriting data in string1[i].

Comment: @Matias04_ 99% of programming errors are, don't be hard on yourself.

Comment: Changing counLetters() to take a `const char *` would have made the problem more obvious. As would enabling more warnings.

Comment: @Owl: Seriously. Mistakes are part of the learning process. I strongly believe thoughts such as "I'm dumb" are detrimental to progress and should be rejected as false.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, agree 100%. What matters really is that you can find any mistake quickly. And that's done through clear code structure, a lucid understanding of what you want to do and testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **equal equal to** operator instead of **assignment** operator in if condition like this

> if(string1==latter)

in your if condition `if(string1=latter)` value of latter variable is assign to `string1[i]`